# How to use media queries to move one div above another div

Tags: html, css, frontend, media-queries, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to make a website and I am trying to make the website more responsive across all devices.

When someone is using a mobile device I want the div that holds the image to be above the div that contains the header and paragraph text, but I am not sure how to do that.

**This is what it currently looks like on mobile:**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```css
h3:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
  bottom: -10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>About | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" /> -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/about.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
        
    
        <!-- ABOUT US SECTION  START -->
    <section>
        <div class="container text-start mt-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <h3 class="display-3 text-start" id="about" pt-5>About Us</h3>
                <br>
                <!-- <br> -->
                <p class="text-start">
                    We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.
                    Through the utilization of state-of-the-art equipment, we provide essential hands-on support that gives businesses the ability to effectively operate and maintain the crucial systems that keep them afloat.
                </p>
                <br>
                <p class="text-start">
                    At , we are geared toward using the power of technology to help our clients achieve their business objectives whether it is a client who may be embarking on a new project or are in the process of executing a pre-existing plan. No matter the situation, we promise the smooth and effortless completion of your new or current projects. We are committed to delivering excellent results to our clients to help them achieve their goals and promote growth.
                </p>
                <br />
                <div class="d-grid  col-6 mx-auto mb-4 text-start">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <img src="./src/img/about-001.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded float-start mb-3" alt="IT technicians working">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        <!-- ABOUT US SECTION  CLOSE -->
```

### Similar Problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--divinectorweb.com-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CCTV Services |</title>
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all-services.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
        
    <!-- CCTV SERVICES SECTION START -->
    <section>
        <div class="container text-left mt-5">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md col-12 order-1 order-md-0">
                <h3 class="display-3 text-start" id="long">CCTV Services</h3>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <b>CCTV Services</b> are an essential component of any business. CCTV provides real-time monitoring of multiple locations; the security they supply is indispensable, allowing businesses to have peace of mind knowing that their CCTV system is working 24/7 to keep their employees, customers, and partners safe.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    So when something goes amiss it is of utmost importance to get the right CCTV Support that has technicians who are equipped with the tools needed to get your CCTV system back online. So whether your cameras receive their power through LTE, solar energy, or anything in between we have the necessary equipment to get you back into action.
                    <br />
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto mb-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md col-12 order-0 order-md-1">
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="./src/img/cctv-003.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded float-start mb-3" alt="IT technician working">
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
    <!-- CCTV SERVICES SECTION CLOSE -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

### My Network Tab

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

Note: I replaced your image with a dummy image for the snippet to work

```css
h3:after {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
     bottom: -10px;
     content: "";
     display: block;
     height: 2px;
     position: relative;
     width: 100px;
}
 @media (min-width: 300px) {
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>About | </title>
      <!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" /> -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css" /> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/about.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- ABOUT US SECTION  START -->
      <section>
         <div class="container text-start mt-3">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md col-12 order-1 order-md-0">
                  <h3 class="display-3 text-start" id="about" pt-5>About Us</h3>
                  <br>
                  <!-- <br> -->
                  <p class="text-start">
                     We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.
                     Through the utilization of state-of-the-art equipment, we provide essential hands-on support that gives businesses the ability to effectively operate and maintain the crucial systems that keep them afloat.
                  </p>
                  <br>
                  <p class="text-start">
                     At , we are geared toward using the power of technology to help our clients achieve their business objectives whether it is a client who may be embarking on a new project or are in the process of executing a pre-existing plan. No matter the situation, we promise the smooth and effortless completion of your new or current projects. We are committed to delivering excellent results to our clients to help them achieve their goals and promote growth.
                  </p>
                  <br />
                  <div class="d-grid  col-6 mx-auto mb-4 text-start">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md col-12 order-0 order-md-1">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="img-fluid rounded float-start mb-3" alt="IT technicians working">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- ABOUT US SECTION  CLOSE -->
```

**Explanation:**

I changed `col` to `col-md` for both the text and the image so the columns get dynamic width only after a certain(intermediate) screen width.

I added `col-12` for the image and the text so they take full width and collapse on top of each other below intermediate screen width.

I used `order-md-x` and `order-x` to order the items at different screen width.

Comment: thank you so much I really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: I added some code to my original question because I have a similar problem but when I use the code you gave I don't get the same solution

Comment: I ran and the updated code and it worked for me, at first it didn't but later I figured the bootstrap import was missing in the header, not sure if that's the same issue you're facing.

Comment: i have bootstrap imported but i don't know why it's still not working I update my question again to include my links

Comment: that code just worked for me, check if there is something else overriding your styles

Comment: you're right but I don't get it I only have one CSS file linked to the HTML and when I copy the exact code I have in my HTML and CSS into codepen.io it works but on the live server I'm using doesn't show that it worked.

Comment: try inspecting the page and checking if the css file is served on that page using the network tab

Comment: I added a picture of my network tab to my original post I don't know if the CSS file is being served to the page

Comment: any clue on why it's not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired responsive layout using Bootstrap 5, you can utilize its grid system and ordering classes. Here's how you can structure your HTML and apply the necessary classes:

```css
/* Style for the image div */
.col-md-6.order-md-2 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Style for the header and text div */
.col-md-6.order-md-1 {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Media Query for screens with max-width of 767px (small screens) */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-md-6.order-md-2 img,
    .col-md-6.order-md-1 {
        width: 100%; /* Make the columns stack on top of each other */
        padding: 10px; /* Reduce padding for smaller screens */
        border: none; /* Remove border on smaller screens */
    }

    .col-md-6.order-md-1 {
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Reduce spacing between the divs */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
            <!-- This div holds the image -->
            <img src="your-image-source" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
            <!-- This div contains the header and paragraph text -->
            <h2>Your Header</h2>
            <p>Your paragraph text here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation of the code:

The container class is used to create a responsive fixed-width container.

The row class is used to create a horizontal row to hold your columns.

The col-md-6 class is applied to both columns. This class indicates that each column should occupy half of the available width on medium-sized screens (and larger).

The order-md-2 class is applied to the first column (image div). This class changes the order of the columns on medium-sized screens and larger, making the image div appear second.

The order-md-1 class is applied to the second column (header and text div). This class changes the order of the columns on medium-sized screens and larger, making this div appear first.

This arrangement will ensure that on smaller screens (like mobile devices), the image div appears above the header and paragraph text div, creating the responsive layout you're aiming for.

Make sure to replace "your-image-source", "Your Header", and "Your paragraph text here." with the actual content and image source you're using.

Bootstrap's grid system and utility classes like order-md-* make it relatively easy to create responsive layouts without needing to write custom CSS for every breakpoint.

Comment: thank you but can you please help take a look at a similar problem if you read the comments under Dhia's answer you will understand my current situation thank you

Comment: i don't know why but your code didn't work for me any idea on what might be the problem. I think it might be the same thing that's happening when I try Dhia's solution