# How to move one div above another div in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to make a website and I am trying to make the website more responsive across all devices.

When someone is using a mobile device I want the div that holds the image to be above the div that contains the header and paragraph text, I previously asked a question on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76838308/how-to-use-media-queries-to-move-one-div-above-another-div/76838405?noredirect=1#comment135464289_76838405) and the answer I got worked for one page of my site but didn't work for the others. The solution I was given is the the snippet below. Thank you.

```css
body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    /* font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; */
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    h3:after {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        bottom: -10px;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
     }
}

h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--divinectorweb.com-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CCTV Services |</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all-services.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
        
    <!-- CCTV SERVICES SECTION START -->
    <section>
        <div class="container text-left mt-5">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md col-12 order-1 order-md-0">
                <h3 class="display-3 text-start" id="long">CCTV Services</h3>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <b>CCTV Services</b> are an essential component of any business. CCTV provides real-time monitoring of multiple locations; the security they supply is indispensable, allowing businesses to have peace of mind knowing that their CCTV system is working 24/7 to keep their employees, customers, and partners safe.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    So when something goes amiss it is of utmost importance to get the right CCTV Support that has technicians who are equipped with the tools needed to get your CCTV system back online. So whether your cameras receive their power through LTE, solar energy, or anything in between we have the necessary equipment to get you back into action.
                    <br />
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto mb-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md col-12 order-0 order-md-1">
                <!-- <div class="col"> -->
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/300" class="img-fluid rounded float-start mb-3" alt="IT technician working">
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
    </section>
    <!-- CCTV SERVICES SECTION CLOSE -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the classes `row` and `col`, you could use the [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) classes.

- I used `d-flex` to tell it to use flex.
- The container should layout as a column by default and use reverse order: `flex-column-reverse`
- When bigger than small, `flex-md-row` tells the container to layout as a row instead and not use reverse order.
- When bigger than small, `col-md-6` tells each column in the row to use half of bootstrap's 12 part grid system.

```html
<section>
    <div class="container text-left mt-5">
    
        <div class="d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="display-3 text-start" id="long">CCTV Services</h3>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <b>CCTV Services</b> are an essential component of any business. CCTV provides real-time monitoring of multiple locations; the security they supply is indispensable, allowing businesses to have peace of mind knowing that their CCTV system is working 24/7 to keep their employees, customers, and partners safe.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    So when something goes amiss it is of utmost importance to get the right CCTV Support that has technicians who are equipped with the tools needed to get your CCTV system back online. So whether your cameras receive their power through LTE, solar energy, or anything in between we have the necessary equipment to get you back into action.
                    <br />
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto mb-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- <div class="col"> -->
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/300" class="img-fluid rounded float-start mb-3" alt="IT technician working">
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you but one quick question, where would I need to insert `col-12` so that the columns can have the same size as before?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `col-md-6` on each cell and to break at medium, rather than small. The only thing you may want to tweak is some minor margins/padding, but that can be an exercise for the reader ;-)